# Проблема с шифрованием и дешифровкой строки

Tags: python

Cделал шифровщик на Python, а вот когда начал заниматься дешифровщиом не выводит. Как это исправить?
(Это отрывок)

```
for i in range(0, length):
c = ime[i]
c = c.upper()
if (c == "А"):
print("11!")
elif (c == "Б"):
print("13@")
elif (c == "В"):
print("15#")
```

А вот дешифровщик, почему-то не выводит вообще ничего (это отрывок)
Помогите!

```
ime = input("Введите символы для дешифровки: \n\n")
length = len(ime)

for i in range(0, length):
c = ime[i]
c = c.upper()
if (c == "11!"):
print("А")
elif (c == "13@"):
print("Б")
```

У меня, например, на входе 13@. Вот у меня есть условие на проверку.Но есть одна проблема: у меня `С` в данном случае не 13@, а 1, у меня в `с` только 1 значение. Если я сравниваю `с` с "15#", то у меня `с` == 1. Оно берет 1 символ строки. Проще говоря, у меня `с` всегда один символ.

Как это исправить?

Comment: Можете правильно код скопировать? В Питоне индентация важна, и насколько я понимаю, проблема именно в ней, но в куске кода, который вы привели, ее вообще нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените цикл на `for i in ime`, так оно будет проходить по символам в строке, а также замените `c = c.upper` на `с = i.upper`. И да, скорее всего, проблема в том, что вы сравниваете 1 символ с несколькими.
Решается так:

```
from textwrap import wrap
ime = input()
a = wrap(ime, 3) #Возвращает список из строки разделенной на 3,например ['11!', '13@']
for i in a:
    if i == '11!':
        print('A')
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, очень помогли

Comment: Незачто)И да,в следующий раз отмечайте ответ как верный.

Answer (score 2):

Кодируем, например, «БА». Получается «13@11!».

`ime` имеет значение «», а `length`, значение 6. Первый символ именно 1.

А вам нужно получить часть текста. Для этого используется оператор `[:]` К примеру:

```
"Hello"[1:3] = "el"
"Hello"[2:5] = "llo"
```